# accordian color change for active cell

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the accordian with alternative color even after activating.Now I want to change the same color for active cell.Now I want to maintain active title is in purple color and and active desc is in grey color.

Now working properly for purple title with grey desc but grey title need to change puprle color and desc is in grey color.

eg:if I click chennai,chennai -india title is in purple color and its desc is in grwy hydrabad -india is also in purple color and gurgon -india is in purple(working now)

if I click hydrabad ,chennai -india title is in purple color,hydrabad -india is also in purple color and hydrabad's desc in in grey and gurgon -india is in purple again

if I click gurgoan hydrabad wants to grey and chennai is in purple
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L1npuw9z/1/)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.view-content .contactDesc:first').css('display','block');
 $('.view-content .contactTitle:first , .view-content .contactDesc:first').addClass('active');
 $('.view-content .contactTitle:first .glyphicon').addClass('rotate');
 $('.officeAddress .colorme:visible:odd').addClass('grey');
    $('.officeAddress .colorme:visible:even').addClass('purple');
    $('.contactTitle').click(function(){ 
    if(!$(this).hasClass('active')){
 $('.contactTitle .glyphicon ').removeClass('rotate');
 $(this).find('span.glyphicon').toggleClass('rotate');
      $('.contactDesc').slideUp();
      $('.contactTitle').removeClass('active');
   $('.contactDesc').removeClass('active');
   $(this).next('.contactDesc').addClass('active');
      $(this).next('.contactDesc').slideDown(function(){
      $('.officeAddress .colorme').removeClass('grey').removeClass('purple');
          $('.officeAddress .colorme:visible:odd').addClass('grey');
          $('.officeAddress .colorme:visible:even').addClass('purple');
      });
      $(this).addClass('active');
    } 
     });
});
```

```css
.officeAddress{
  width:960px;
  margin:0 auto;
  font-family: Raleway;
 }
.contactTitle{
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 18px 40px 18px 40px;
 font-size:20px;
 width: 100%;
 }
.contactDesc{
 display:none;
 font-size:23px;
 padding: 40px 0 0px 0;
 font-family: Raleway-Regular;
 }
.ContactAddressHeading p,.currentOpening{
 width: 960px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 font-size: 30px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color:#000000;
 padding: 38px 0px 0px 0;
 text-align: center;
 } 
  
.rotate {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
} 
.container-fluid{
 /*padding:0 !important;*/
} 
.officeAddress .purple{
  background:#663399;
  color:#ffffff;
}
.contentWidth .purple,.contentWidth .purple p{color:#ffffff;}
.purple .glyphicon{
 color:#5d218b;
}
.grey{
  background:#f7f7f7;
  color:#6c2a9f;
}
.grey .glyphicon{color:#e2dfdf;}
.purple .row-1-col-1,.purple .row-1-col-1-right,.purple .col-email a,.purple p{
 color:#ffffff;
}
.grey .col-email a{
 color:#000000;
}
.contactTitle.purple{
 color:#ffffff;
}
.contactTitle h3{
  display: inline;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Raleway-Medium;
}

.contactTitle .glyphicon{float: right;top: 6px;} 
.form_image{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: 85px;
}
.form_image img{
 width: 960px;
 height: auto; 
}
#ContactAddressHeading { margin-bottom: 55px;}
#contact{ margin-bottom: 60px;
    max-width: 960px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.contactDesc {display: none;font-size: 18px; min-height:100px;}
.col-img { margin-bottom:10px; }
.row-1-col-1 { float:left; padding: 0px 0 0px 70px;}
.row-1-col-1-right { min-height: 250px;float:right; padding: 0px 40px 0px 0;}
.addressImg{float:left;}
.col-address,.col-tele,.col-email{padding-left: 15px;float:left;font-size: 14px;}
.col-address span{font-family: Raleway-SemiBold;font-size: 14px;}
.address, .tele , .email{display:inline-block;font-size: 14px;}
.row-1-col-1-right .tele{
 width: 100%;
}
.address{padding-bottom: 5px;}
.grey .row-1-col-1,.grey .row-1-col-1-right,.grey .row-1-col-1 p,.grey .row-1-col-1-right p{color:#000000;}
.col-email p,.col-email div,.col-tele p,.col-tele div{display:inline;}
.contactDesc  .views-row{padding-bottom:40px;}
.col-address div p {font-size: 14px;font-family: Raleway-Regular;margin: 0 0 1px;}
.officeAddress:last-child {margin-bottom: 60px;}
#contact .view-content{
 margin-bottom: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contact">
 <div class="view view-contact view-id-contact view-display-id-block view-dom-id-4a9293a6aa6b278d4666989fe61a9db4">
  <div class="view-content row">
   <div class="officeAddress ">
    <div class="contactTitle colorme col-sm-12 col-md-12 active purple">
     <h3>Chennai -India</h3>
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right rotate"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="contactDesc col-sm-12 col-md-12 colorme active grey" style="display: block;">
     <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 row-1-col-1 views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
      <div class="address">
                         desc
                        </div>
      <div class="tele"></div>
      <div class="contactMail"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="officeAddress ">
    <div class="contactTitle colorme col-sm-12 col-md-12 purple">
     <h3>Hyderabad - India</h3>
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="contactDesc col-sm-12 col-md-12 colorme" style="display: none;">
     <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 row-1-col-1 views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first views-row-last">
      <div class="address">
        desc
      </div>
      <div class="tele"></div>
      <div class="contactMail"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="officeAddress ">
    <div class="contactTitle colorme col-sm-12 col-md-12 grey">
     <h3>Gurgaon -India</h3>
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="contactDesc col-sm-12 col-md-12 colorme" style="display: none;">
     <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 row-1-col-1 views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first views-row-last">
      <div class="address">
       desc
      </div>
      <div class="tele"></div>
      <div class="contactMail"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so how you want the output?

Comment: active title is in pruple and active desc is in grey always

Comment: what about inactive titles? how you want them to be displayed then

Comment: please check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/L1npuw9z/2/... if this is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I made following change in your script. Please check the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L1npuw9z/2/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.view-content .contactDesc:first').css('display','block');
    $('.view-content .contactTitle:first , .view-content .contactDesc:first').addClass('active');
    $('.view-content .contactTitle:first .glyphicon').addClass('rotate');
    $('.officeAddress .colorme:visible:odd').addClass('grey');
    $('.officeAddress .colorme:visible:even').addClass('purple');
    $('.contactTitle').click(function(){ 
          if(!$(this).hasClass('active')){
            $('.contactTitle .glyphicon ').removeClass('rotate');
            $(this).find('span.glyphicon').toggleClass('rotate');
            $('.contactDesc').slideUp();
            $('.contactTitle').removeClass('active');
            $('.contactDesc').removeClass('active');
            $(this).next('.contactDesc').addClass('active');
            $(this).next('.contactDesc').slideDown(function(){
              $('.officeAddress .colorme').removeClass('grey').removeClass('purple');
              $('.officeAddress .colorme:odd').addClass('grey');
              $('.officeAddress .colorme:even').addClass('purple');
            });
            $(this).addClass('active');
          } 
     });
});
```